# Why is my Parameter not being substituted?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using the following query to query CosmosDB, I cannot use LINQ because of the ARRAY_CONTAINS, The issue is that my app crashes with a null exception because the SQLParameter is never substituted.

The query looks like this

```
     var sqlStatement = new SqlQuerySpec
    {
      QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.locales[0].categories, @category)",
      Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
    {
       new SqlParameter{ Name = "@category", Value = "Homeware" }
    }
  };

   IDocumentQuery<JObject> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(
 collectionUr
 sqlStatement)
 .AsDocumentQuery();

 while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
  items.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<JObject>());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to below code which works for me:

```
var Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
       {
          new SqlParameter(Name = "@category", Value = "Homeware")
       };

IQueryable<Pojo> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Pojo>(
        uri,
        new SqlQuerySpec
        {
         QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.locales[0].categories, " + Parameters[0].Value + ")" 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but Jay's answer is wrong. His way doesn't actually parameterise the SqlQuerySpec but instead it just concatenates the string which in return doesn't properly parameterise the query. It's the same as not having the parameters collection to begin with.

I just tested the code you provided with the exact same dataset you have and it's absolutely fine. The null exception has nothing to do with your `SqlParameterCollection`.

Same code working:

[image]

Dataset used

[image: ![]()]